# Retrofit parse array of strings

Tags: android, retrofit

I have troubles with parsing of server response using retrofit. Server returns array of strings, how it's possible to parse this: ["1", "21", "22"] using retrofit framework. I'm using Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2.
Thanks

Comment: Please add your existing code so that we can understand it better! And also include the errors you face while trying your way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To parse that response define your method in API interface like this:

```
@GET("methodThatReturnsArray")
Call<ArrayList<String>> methodThatReturnsArray();
```

Synchronous call would look like

```
Call<ArrayList<String>> call = retrofitService.methodThatReturnsArray();
Response response = call.execute();
ArrayList<String> arrayOfStrings = response.body();
```